# Android : How to make a layout visible when back is pressed to hide keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I'm using linear layout with `alignParentBottom="true"` and a relative layout with same property but aligned above the linear layout. i have placed an edit text. the keyboard is shown when edittext is focussed. at that time of showing keyboard, the bottom linear layout hides the edittext. the user will not be able to see what is being typed in the edit text.

Now, I'm hiding the bottom linear layout by setting visibility in activity when the keyboard is shown. `OnFocusChanged` of the edittext, i'm making the bottom linear layout visible. But, How to make a layout visible when back is pressed to hide keyboard?

In Manifest.xml i use following code for my activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativetop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mymenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/top_arrow_r_click" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mymenu"
        android:background="@drawable/sera" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/search"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>

        <!-- android:background="@drawable/search_edittext_round_corner" -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_icon_click" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/of" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/relativecent1"
     android:layout_above="@+id/linearbottom"
     android:layout_below="@+id/relativetop"
     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
 >
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:text="Pay Just Rs 4999 and get a Professional Fashion Portfolio with Make up worth "
    android:textColor="#2d3438" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@drawable/nor_bg"
    android:src="@drawable/loading" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="$ 299"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#be2e33"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/updown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/like_click" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/up"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@drawable/unlike_click" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/updowncount"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/updown"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/upcount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/downcount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Times Deals"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="#3b84c4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="At"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:background="@drawable/wallet_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/map_click"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Show on Map"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
     android:textColor="#3b84c4" 
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Add to Wallet"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textColor="#3b84c4" />
```

```
<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/relativedetail"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/relativecenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <!-- android:background="@drawable/round_corner_deals_detail" --> 

    <!-- DETAILS -->
    <ScrollView
     android:id="@+id/scrolview"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/line"
     android:visibility="visible"
     android:layout_margin="5dp" >


         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/detailsText"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametttt"
             android:textColor="#2d3438"
             android:visibility="visible" />
```

```
    <!-- REVIEW -->
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/relativereview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearbottom"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/line"

        >
<RelativeLayout

     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="5dp"  
    >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/postreview" 
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_edittext"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="60dp" 
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_margin="2dp" >
        </EditText>
      <Button
             android:id="@+id/post"
             android:layout_below="@+id/postreview"
             android:background="@drawable/apply_click"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/postreview"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
             android:paddingRight="35dp"
             android:paddingLeft="5dp"
             android:text="Post Review" />



</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlist"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/relativereview"
     >
     <ListView
                 android:layout_below="@+id/post"
                 android:id="@+id/listreview"
             android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
             android:listSelector="#00000000"
             android:divider="#00000000"
             android:background="#00000000"
             android:dividerHeight="1dp"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
                      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:visibility="invisible"
          android:layout_below="@+id/line" 
         android:id="@+id/relativedetails_layout"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/imageView2"
             android:layout_width="120dp"
             android:layout_height="90dp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/detailsText"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/detailsText"
             android:src="@drawable/reliance_logo" />
         <!-- android:background="@drawable/round_corner_category_listing_page" -->

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView8"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/detailsText"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
             android:text="Reliance Fresh"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:textStyle="bold" />


         <ListView
             android:id="@+id/ListViewMalls"
             android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
             android:listSelector="@drawable/deals_details_bg"
             android:divider="#00000000"
             android:dividerHeight="1dp"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
             android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView14"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:background="@drawable/bagg" />


         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView15"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView14"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView14"
             android:text="More deals from"
             android:focusable="true"
             android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
             android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
             android:ellipsize="marquee"
             android:scrollHorizontally="true"
             android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ListViewMalls"
             android:textSize="10dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
             android:textColor="#3b84c4" />

         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/textView16"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"
             android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
              android:textColor="#000000"
             android:text="Reliance Fresh"
              android:textSize="12dp"
               android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
             android:ellipsize="marquee"
             android:scrollHorizontally="true"
             />

     </RelativeLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <!-- android:background="@drawable/round_corner_sort" -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Details"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />
          <!-- android:background="@drawable/round_corner_button_sort" -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/store"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="Store"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/review"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
             android:textColor="#000000"
             android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Review"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearbottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/linebg"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearmap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/map_norm"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMap"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Map"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lineartrends"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/trends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/trends_nor"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTrends"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Trends"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearwatch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/watch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/watch_nor"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textWatch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Watch"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearcontrol"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/control"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/control_nor"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textControl"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Control"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearme"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/me"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/me_nor"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Me"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Its not needed Play visible/hide game. Instead you can try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Can you show your code? Also as @PareshMayani mentioned you have to use windowssoftinput mode in your manifest file

Comment: Please read and understand this article: [Android windowSoftInputMode – Resize the application for the soft-keyboard](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/)

Comment: @Venky : Updated with my xml layout code

Comment: Give full XML , some code is missing when i tried to see you Graphical Layout.. Use http://www.pastie.org

Comment: @Venky: i have posted full code

Answer (score 1):

You can use onBackPressed for that, but the problem is that you will not be able to detect if the keyboard is shown or not. Actually, if you will check that your layout is invisible, it could mean that the keyboard is shown, and in onBackPressed you can make it visible again, and that's it.

Comment: onBackPressed is overrided to execute our set of code during exit of  the activity.

Comment: This is not a problem. If your layout is invisible, you make it visible, and return, without exiting the application. Or is not this back you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The code you put up here is very confusing, so i will just concentrate on the question you asked.
Override onBackPressed method. in that, whichever layout you want to make visible, use setVisible method and set it to true and to hide the keyboard :-

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) Login.this.getSystemService(android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(Login.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

or if you want to see the edittext which is currently being hidden because of the keyboard, you can shift your view upwards. Android provides this functionality by default
For example :- on my login activity, my password edittext shifts upwards when keyboard appears  and i am able to see what i am typing.